# Confusion on how to execute javascript server-side vs client-side

Tags: javascript, node.js, server-side, client-side

I'm unsure if I'm asking the right question here. I apologize in advance for my ignorance, I'm only a year into teaching myself full stack JS and web app architecture and I'm trying to understand this on a granular level. Previous attempts to ask this question seem to offend some devs, so maybe it's a dumb question.

I'm trying to understand how to, or if its possible to, explicitly designate or assign a specific file or block of javascript to process/run/execute on a server vs on the client/browser.

Writing some javascript in a an app.js file and running `node app.js` seems to still expose that script to the browser, viewable in the Sources tab in Dev Tools.

PHP is interpreted by a server and then sends static HTML to the client. Is this "pre-processing", the equivalent of Server Side Rendering with Javascript App frameworks? Or Is writing a .php file inline with HTML server-side (like you'd see in Wordpress) more equivalent to inline javascript client side? And there is a different method to have JS interpreted server-side?

I've been reading about GENERATE_SOURCEMAP, but that seems more like it's used to hide client-side JS modules.

**Other possible wordings of this question**

- How to not expose server side Javascript to the client?
- How to run/execute Javascript on a server vs in browser?

*I am **NOT ASKING** for the definition of server-side vs client-side JS, or for suggestions of server side application frameworks.*

Again, I think i've confused myself or missing something very basic. Maybe the only answer is to segment your private web application from your client application and access via API. Thank you for any help.

Comment: The only thing ever exposed to the browser in a node.js server are things the node.js server itself is directly exposing to the browser via something like express.static, or by the webserver serving your node.js app. app.js on a node server should *not* be exposed to the client if configured properly.

Comment: *"explicitly designate or assign a specific file or block of javascript to process/run/execute on a server vs on the client/browser"* - You seem to be thinking about this the wrong way.  You don't designate in the code itself, block by block or line by line, what parts are "for the server" and what parts are "for the client".  Whatever you write in your NodeJS app is server-side code.  The fact that it's also written in JavaScript is irrelevant.  The browser can't see what the server does internally.  Whatever the server sends to the client, that's what the browser uses.

Comment: A Node program need not have a single thing to do with serving web pages, and in particular running `node app.js` only makes the JavaScript source for "app.js" visible if that is what the web server intended to do.

Comment: The default of an express server is for the server itself to not be served to the client, if the client can access server-side code it's because you have nginx or apache statically serving the entire directory when it shouldn't be.

Comment: When running `node app.js` are any modules imported to app.js exposed or no? node.js built in server default is to expose a JS file to the client but express server defaults to only interpreting server-side unless otherwise configured? So visibility of server side javascript, or whats sent to the client to interpret, is dependent upon the configuration of the web server? Is there a difference between sending js to the client and having js visible to the client? or any js sent to/accessible by the client is interpreted by the client?

Comment: @BryanZawlocki: We can't really tell you whether any specific server or code you have is visible to clients or not.  Can you provide a [mcve] which is a Node application that runs a web server (most likely Express, but not necessarily) and allows clients to view code you think they shouldn't?

Comment: @David excellent investigative question, thank you. Poorly worded on my part. I'm not really sure if supposed to be seeing it or not, since I'm understanding where/how that delineation of server/client interpretation is happening. Docusuarus for example, yes a front-end react app, I'm able to see the entire src & docs folder and their contents client-side, but not any of the config.js files in the parent folder. Based on your comments, I'm assuming Docusuaurs' CLI commands are installed as a binary which runs a separate server application to render and serve the site?

Comment: @BryanZawlocki: I'm not familiar with that tool, sorry.  A React app would be entirely client-side.  (Though I've heard of "server-side rendering" tools, but am not familiar with them or what they accomplish on a technical level.)  CLI commands are essentially beside the point, since they're not part of the browser/server interaction over HTTP.

Comment: I have another project that I own, that I hired some devs more skilled than I to build, built with Next and Nest. Next is a primarily a front-end framework as I understand but renders everything into chunks where I'm not seeing the project files exposed to the client. I understand this is highly depended upon individual project architecture, I'm just trying to understand where the server/client "segmentation" of JS logic generally happens. Coming from Wordpress, writing some php in a .php file, is just inherently interpreted by the server and the result output to the client.

Comment: @David Docusaurus is just a SPA React doc site generator. Here's a link to its basic architecture https://docusaurus.io/docs/advanced/architecture

Comment: This sounds a bit like you would benefit from reading about how the client/server architecture works with a web browser.  The only Javascript that executes client-side is Javascript that you explicitly put in web pages that are served back to the browser where the browser can then run that Javascript.  The only Javascript that executes server-side is Javascript that your nodejs app specifically loads, calls and runs.

Answer (score 1):

Summary: Your JavaScript executed by the node daemon on the server side is not visible on the client side, the only thing visible is the output of your JS.

When you create a file with the `.php` extension you need an executable that executes this file, to return the result to the client to render it.

For example  :

- create a php file `index.php` with the following syntax:

```
<?php
    echo '<script>console.log("HelloWorled")</script>'
?>
```

to run this file, you need the PHP daemon (the php interpreter) to run the file to get this output `<script>console.log("HelloWorled")</script>`
next; the output will be returned to the client  to be execute on client browser;

In the case of PHP this operation is managed directly by the http server such as nginx via this configuration:

```
server{
   location ~ \.php$ {
     include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
     fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php<version>-fpm.sock;
   }
}
```

which you will find inside the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file

This rule simply tells nginx to make all files with the `.php` extension go through the php proxy to be executed and then return only the result of the execution to the client.

You have to imagine the exact same thing with nodejs.

I created an `index.js` file with the following syntax :

```
....
process.write( '<script>console.log("HelloWorled")</script>');
....
```

running the file with `node index.js` you will just get the output `<script>console.log("HelloWorled")</script>` which your server (e.g. expressJS) will send back to the client to run it client side to get los same result of the php code.

NOTES :

- YOU DON'T NEED TO EXPOSE YOUR JS CODE, YOU NEED ONLY A PROXY TO SERVER IT Like PHP WITH NGINX (read more about [expressJS](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) and the other nodejs servers frameworks).
- IF you need to expose a client side scripts,images,styles, you need to specify it in your [proxy configuration](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html#serving-static-files-in-express)

Comment: This is the most useful and succinct explanation I have received so far, thank you! I will take a dive into this tonight and tomorrow. Does node.js have any built in proxy ability? or a frame work like express, php/nginx equivalent is a must?

Comment: expressjs is the most popular frameworks to create a http server for node;
but if you want, you can use directly the nodejs native `http` module